# How to make a new branch in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: git, visual-studio, branch, git-branch

I am using Git with Visual Studio Online in Visual Studio 2015 and am trying to figure out how to create a branch.

This is the usual answer on the internet: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850437.aspx & https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj190809.aspx#create

If you check the image it shows the branch and the drop down arrow where I assume you can create a branch. But in Visual Studio 2105 the dropdown is not there and when I click on the link it goes to branches.

But there is only Merge, Rebase, and Actions dropdowns. There is no new branch.

So how can I create a new branch in Visual Studio 2015?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just look one further down in the branches hub.  You see it has Active Git Repositories, and presumably showing yours.  It can be opened, and show your master branch.
Right click that one, and you get a context menu including "New Local Branch from..."

Comment: ah thank you, silly me. tablets have turned me off right clicking :P

Comment: I came till here, but 'Create Branch' button is disable. Some clue, please? https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=2516236AC4CD5FA3!1332&authkey=!ADT5ZNfiESY_lg8&v=3&ithint=photo%2cpng

Comment: Try the drop down in "Select a branch", you need to tell it from which branch you will branch out.  In your case it seems you only can select master.  When you have selected your "source" branch the Create Branch button will light up.  It also looks like you don't have the latest version, you should see a list of branches below your repo, and right clicking one of them, not the top node, will automatically fill out the Select branch field for you.  One step less to do.

Comment: The text box for Create Branch is still disabled after all the above steps. This worked before, but after the Win10 Anniversary Update and under VS update 3, it is now like this for me. This was my first try to make a new branch after the Win10 update.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem that the select branch was empty, the create branch was disabled and I had win10 anniversary. Then I realised I hadn't committed anything locally. Once I had the button and drop down became active.