# Using Git and Visual Studio 2015 to pull, edit and push files

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2015

I've been having trouble using Github and Visual Studio 2015 together. It has been hard finding tutorials that show you how to do what I want to do, especially for Visual Studio 2015.

How can I pull from the master branch in a Github repo, then edit files pulled from that repo to upload it to a new separate branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to make a new branch in visual studio 2015?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30413834/how-to-make-a-new-branch-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: Create a new branch from the branch that you want to work on. Then work in this branch and if you are done push it to the server.

Comment: @Allan Are you using the GitHub extension for visual studio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VS2015 open up Team Explorer (View -> Team Explorer), select manage connections (power plug icon).

Here you should see a tab titled Local Git Repositories.

Select Clone then enter the url of the github repo you would like to clone.

[image: Git Clone in VS2015]

Now you can open the local repository by selecting from the list right click -> open

This will take you to the Team Explorer home tab for the repository here, select Branches

[image: Team Explorer Home]

This will take you to branches screen, here you can select a branch, right click -> New Local Branch From...

[image: Branches Tab]

You will be prompted to name your branch, then click Create Branch

[image: Create Branch]

Your branch will be automatically checkout if checkout branch is ticked, otherwise it should appear in the list of branches where you can right click -> checkout.

Now you are free to make any changes. Once you are ready to commit select the changes tab from the Team Explorer Home menu. You can see all the changes here you have the option of staging, by right clicking each file you would like to commit and staging it, or committing all changes by selecting commit all.

[image: Changes Tab]

Now the changes are commited to your local repo, to push to a new remote branch you will need to publish. To do this go to the Sync tab from the Team Explorer home tab and select publish.

[image: Sync Tab]

Answer (score 1):

In your terminal you can use the following git commands.

`git clone https://github.com/project/url`
`cd new_project_folder`
`git checkout master` This will make sure you are on the master branch.
`git checkout -b new_branch_name` This creates a new branch off of master

open project in Visual studio and make changes as desired.

Back in terminal
`git add .` This will stage all your changes
`git commit -m 'write your commit message here'`  Commit your changes
`git push -u origin new_branch_name` This will push your changes to GitHub

See more documentation on how to use Git here
[Git Documentation](https://git-scm.com/documentation)

Answer (score 0):

1. Clone the repository
2. From the remotes/origin, make a new local copy of master (New Local Branch From)
3. From your local master, create a new local banch (whatever you call your feature branch). This will switch you to your new local branch.
4. Edit files.
5. Commit files.
6. Publish the branch. This will upload the new branch and edits to the github repo.